# Expressões regulares para corrigir o formato de um campo enquanto este é digitado

Tags: javascript, regex

Preciso de ajuda com 2 expressões regulares em JavaScript para validar duas formas de entrada de dados num input HTML.

1) A primeira regra é para RNE seguindo:

```
    RNE -> Fixo;
    A-Z, 0-9 -> tamanho 1;
    0-9 -> tamanho 6;
    A-Z, 0-9 -> tamanho 1;
    Exemplos: RNEA409714Z ou RNEZ4097140 ou RNE04097149
```

2) Segunda regra é para RG (Português emitido aqui no Brasil), ele iniciado com a letra W e podem terminar com um número ou letra, sendo:

```
    W -> Fixo
    0-9 -> tamanho 7;
    A-Z, 0-9 -> tamanho 1;
    Exemplos: W0842241A ou W08422410
```

A ideia é conseguir fazer com que os caracteres que não fazem parte das 2 regras sejam ignorados ou removidos do `input`.

Meu código atual é:

```js
function formatarRG(input, teclapres) {
 var numero = input.value.trim().toUpperCase();

 if (numero.substring(0, 1) == 'R' || numero.substring(0, 2) == 'RN' || numero.substring(0, 3) == 'RNE')
  input.value = numero.replace(/^(RNE)([A-Z\d])(\d{6})([A-Z\d])$/, '$1$2$3$4');
 else if (numero.substring(0, 1) == 'W')
  input.value = numero.replace(/^(W)(\d{7})([A-Z\d])$/, '$1$2$3');
 else
  input.value = numero;
  
 return input.value;
}
```

```html
<html>

 <label>Número RG:</label>
 <input type="text" value="" maxlength="14" size="20" onKeyUp="return formatarRG(this, event);" />

<html/>
```

Comment: Uma dica: `{1}` é redundante e pode ser removido. `\d{1}` é o mesmo que `\d` (de modo geral `(qualquercoisa){1}` é o mesmo que `(qualquercoisa)`). Além disso, o `\w` já inclui dígitos, então se tem `\w` não precisa de `\d`. Só que o `\w` também considera o caractere `_`, então na verdade você deveria usar `[A-Z\d]` (letra de A a Z ou dígito de 0 a 9). Outro detalhe é que o `replace` não está fazendo muito sentido, pois vc substitui tudo que encontrou pelas mesmas coisas, e no final a string ficará igual ao que estava antes

Comment: Muito obrigado pelas orientações, farei os ajustes. A ideia é ter um retorno com os caracteres realmente válidos, já desprezando o que não faz parte da regra, por isso que usei o 'replace', você teria algo para indicar ?

Comment: Mas desprezar o que não faz parte talvez seja muito amplo. Se for digitado "Wxyz.2#@0842241d-)(A", vc quer que elimine tudo que não faz parte e só sobre "W0842241A"? Talvez seja mais fácil dizer qual o formato válido e pedir que digite novamente caso não seja, em vez de ficar tentando corrigir o que foi digitado, já que há possibilidades demais a serem tratadas

Comment: hkotsubo, nem tanto!!! você deve ter percebido que meu HTML tem onKeyUp="return formatarRG(this, event);" sendo assim no exemplo "W0842241A", sei que o primeiro caracter digitado tem que ser um W, do segundo ao oitavo tem que ser número e o último (nono) pode ser A-Z, 0-9. eu não queria ficar montando substring e pegar o Char Code do event e desconsiderar o que não for esperado. Achei que haveria algo mais limpo usando regex.

Comment: Poderia se mais claro em sua pergunta, pois no corpo da pergunta está assim "Preciso de ajuda com 2 expressões regulares em JavaScript ..." e o seu código funciona porém lá embaixo na resposta do @FelipeAlmeida você diz que sua pergunta é outra. Eu vou marcar como problema não reproduzível  pois para mim não faz sentido uma pergunta que  não apresenta erro e quando um usuário tenta a responde ela muda de escopo.

Comment: Augusto meu código não funciona como deveria, por isso que pedi ajuda! Você não leu completamente as 2 regras que preciso implementar, eu imaginei que alguém com vasto conhecimento de regex saberia me dizer se existe uma expressão regular que remova os caracteres que não se enquadram nas regras 1 e 2 e mantenha apenas os caracteres que seguem a regra, ou até me dê as devidas orientações para conseguir usar regex para tal finalidade, pois com substrings, ifs, charCode, eu já tenho!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que entendi, você quer ir removendo os caracteres inválidos **à medida em que estes são digitados**. Por exemplo, se depois do "W" só podem ter dígitos, e o usuário digita um "x", a string se torna "Wx", e neste caso o "x" deve ser removido imediatamente após ser digitado, e o valor do `input` volta a ser somente "W".

Bem, fazer isso com regex vai ser bem complicado, pois você tem que avaliar todas as possibilidades para que a substituição seja feita adequadamente:

- quando o primeiro caractere é digitado, tem que verificar se é "W"
- quando o segundo caractere é digitado (assumindo que o primeiro já foi verificado que é "W"), tem que verificar se é um dígito
- quando o terceiro caractere é digitado (assumindo que os 2 primeiros já foram verificados), tem que verificar se é outro dígito
- e assim por diante...

---

Só para a regex não ficar tão confusa, **vamos supor que o critério seja "W seguido de 3 dígitos, seguido de uma letra"**. Uma possível solução seria:

```js
function formatarRG(input, teclapres) {
    let numero = input.value.trim().toUpperCase();
    let r = /^W(\d(\d(\d[A-Z]?)?)?)?$/;
    while (! numero.match(r)) { // enquanto não estiver no formato correto, vai removendo caracteres do input
        numero = numero.slice(0, -1);

        // se já removeu tudo, pode sair do loop
        if (numero.length == 0) break;
    }

    input.value = numero;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <label>Número RG:</label>
  <input type="text" value="" maxlength="14" size="20" onKeyUp="formatarRG(this, event);" />
<html/>
```

A regex é `^W(\d(\d(\d[A-Z]?)?)?)?$`. Ela usa os [marcadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` e `$`, que indicam o início e fim da string, assim eu garanto que ela só pode ter o que está especificado na expressão. Depois temos o `W`. E depois temos o trecho complicado, que verifica todas as possibilidades.

Basicamente, começando de dentro pra fora:

- `\d[A-Z]?`: um dígito seguido opcionalmente por uma letra (o `?` indica que algo é [opcional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html))
- `\d(\d[A-Z]?)?`: um dígito seguido opcionalmente por "um dígito seguido opcionalmente por uma letra"
- `\d(\d(\d[A-Z]?)?)?`: um dígito seguido opcionalmente pela expressão acima
- por fim, a expressão acima também é opcional

Assim, a regex consegue verificar se só tem a letra "W", ou o "W" seguido de apenas um dígito, ou de 2 dígitos, ou de 3 dígitos, ou de 3 dígitos mais uma letra.

> Alguém poderia sugerir usar `^W\d{0,3}[A-Z]?$` (a letra "W", seguida de 0 a 3 dígitos, seguida da uma letra opcional), mas esta regex não serve, pois ela também pega casos como "W1X" e "W12X" (com 1 ou 2 dígitos antes da última letra). Somente a regex acima garante que tem 1, 2 ou 3 dígitos, e que a última letra só ocorre depois do terceiro dígito. Veja a diferença [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/jv1vkn/3/) e [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/jv1vkn/4/).

Enfim, se for digitado algo que não se encaixa, os caracteres do final são removidos, até que se chegue a uma string válida.

---

Agora tente imaginar como ficariam as expressões para os seus critérios. Com 3 dígitos e uma letra já ficou esse negócio - na minha opinião - confuso e de difícil manutenção. Ficaria algo como `^W(\d(\d(\d(\d(\d(\d(\d[A-Z\d]?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?$` - nem conferi para ver se está certa. Para RNE, seria algo como `^R(N(E([A-Z\d](\d(\d(\d(\d(\d(\d[A-Z\d]?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?$`. Ambas são difíceis de entender e podem se tornar pesadelos de manutenção.

---

#### Use regex, mas de outra maneira

Eu ainda acho mais fácil você indicar na sua interface qual o formato correto, e caso o usuário digite algo errado, mostre uma mensagem informativa:

```js
const campo = document.querySelector('#rg');

campo.addEventListener('input', () => {
  campo.setCustomValidity('');
  campo.checkValidity();
});

campo.addEventListener('invalid', () => {
    campo.setCustomValidity('O formato do campo é blablablaetc (informe o formato correto nesta mensagem)');
});
```

```css
/* deixar borda vermelha enquanto o campo for inválido */
input:invalid {
  border: red 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label>Número RG:</label>
  <input id="rg" type="text" value="" required
   pattern="^(W\d{7}[A-Z\d]|RNE[A-Z\d]\d{6}[A-Z\d])$" size="20" />
  <input type="submit" value="ok">
<form/>
```

O [atributo `pattern`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#htmlattrdefpattern) possui uma regex que indica o formato que o campo deve ter: pode ser um RG (o que começa com "W") ou um RNE (o caractere `|` indica [alternância](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html): uma opção **ou** outra). Se o valor digitado estiver errado (ou seja, não corresponde à regex), a regra CSS `input:invalid` é aplicada (e aí você pode estilizar o campo da maneira que achar melhor, por exemplo, para indicar que o formato está errado).

Esta solução não impede que o usuário digite algo inválido, e nem corrige automaticamente o valor. Mas ao tentar submeter o formulário, será mostrada a mensagem correspondente, definida por [`setCustomValidity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Constraint_validation#element.setCustomValidity(message)).

Enfim, uma vez sabendo se o que foi digitado está certo ou não, você cria a sua maneira de informar ao usuário o que está errado e como corrigir.

Comment: hkotsubo, primeiramente parabéns pela explicação; nível de detalhamento e clareza muito impressionante!
Realmente uma aula, parece que você está aqui ao lado explicando... Show! 

Quero agradecer pela resposta a qual me ajudou muito a tomar uma decisão para que rumo seguir.

Um forte abraço.

Answer (score 1):

fiz aqui os regex no site www.regex101.com e criei os seguintes regex

Regex1: `RNE[A-Z0-9][0-9]{1,6}[A-Z0-9]`

Regex2: `W[0-9]{7}[A-Z0-9]`

Testei com os os exemplos que você passou e funcionou perfeitamente!

Comment: grato!!! Sim, tanto o seu regex quanto o meu na validação irá passar, mas a ideia é: no momento da digitação no IMPUT, desprezar os caracteres que não fazem parte da regra e manter os que realmente fazem...

Comment: Felipe Almeida, o código dele funciona não fazendo sentido responder por um problema que não existe.

Comment: Infelizmente você esta errado, basta clicar no botão "Executar" lá encima e faça um teste, digite qualquer coisa que não siga a regra 1 e 2, verá que meu código em function formatarRG(input, teclapres), não funciona como deveria. Até o colega hkotsubo em sua resposta colocou um exemplo "Wxyz.2#@0842241d-)(A" e queria que usando regex elegantemente, o retorno fosse "W0842241A", entende ?